# How do I send an AJAX request to save a really large field to MSSQL?

Tags: javascript, php, sql-server, ajax

I am using Javascript to send an AJAX request to a PHP file so as to save a field into MSSQL however, the field length is massive. This is resulting in the following error being returned to the browser:

> 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

What is the best way for me to send the large field? (probably 5000+ characters)?

Comment: use a POST instead of a GET, and configure PHP to accept larger requests

Comment: FYI: I am using Post. Thanks :)

Comment: I had no way of knowing what you were using :p

Comment: @cleverpaul, can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by changing PHP.ini.

> post_max_size = 20M